# Django reverse foreign key relation doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Hello i am struggling already since 2 days to get a reverse relation going.
I am trying to get pictures of "bilder" into related "doku".
The site returns the  {{doku.name}} but nothing from the loop from the related model "bilder"

I tried almost everything i have found on the internet, but maybe I just have overseen something?

here is my models.py:

```
class Doku(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    inhalt = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    erstellungsdatum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Dokumentation"
        verbose_name_plural = "Dokumentationen"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Bilder(models.Model):
    doku = models.ForeignKey(Doku, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    bilder = models.ImageField(upload_to="bilder/doku/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def Dokus(request):
    doku = Doku.objects.all()
    context = {'doku':doku}
    return render(request, "doku/index.html", context)
```

and my template:

```
{% for doku in doku %}
    <a href="{% url 'apps:DokuDetail' doku.pk %}">{{ doku.name }}</a>
    {{ doku.bilder.name }}


    {% for bilder in doku.bilder_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ bilder.bilder.url }}">
        <p>{{ bilder.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: here's my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = "apps"
urlpatterns = [

    path('doku/', views.Dokus, name="Doku"),
    path('doku/create', views.DokuCreate.as_view(), name="DokuCreate"),
    path('doku/detail/<int:pk>', views.DokuDetail.as_view(), name="DokuDetail"),
    path('doku/update/<int:pk>', views.DokuUpdate.as_view(), name="DokuUpdate"),
    path('doku/delete/<int:pk>', views.DokuDelete.as_view(), name="DokuDelete"),

    path('doku/picadd', views.BilderCreate.as_view(), name="DokuBilderCreate"),


]
```

Comment: Please add your `urls.py` file.

Comment: i am getting the doku name, but not the name of "bilder"

Comment: Isn't just _bilder.url_ enough inside src ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ doku.bilder.name }}` isn't going to work. Remove that.

Similarly, `{{dokubilder.dokubilder.url}}` isn't going to work because there is no `dokubilder` in your template context.

For the models you have posted, looping through `{% for bilder in doku.bilder_set.all %}` in your template should work. If it doesn't, you'll need to provide more information about how to reproduce the problem.

I would suggest that you use different variable names  for the instance and the queryset, e.g. `{% for doku in docku_list %}`. If you change it to `docku_list`, remember to update your view.

```
{% for doku in dokus %}
    <a href="{% url 'apps:DokuDetail' doku.pk %}">{{ doku.name }}</a>

    {% for bilder in doku.bilder_set.all %}
        <p>{{ bilder.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the img tag is useless, it was remaining from a test before. I also tried your solution, it still doesn't work and wasn't working in the last 2 days. I don't get any error, i simply just get the Detail-Link für doku.name but still nothing from the related bilder model :/, what information do you wish? ... could adding a related_name maybe help?

Comment: You can add a related name if you wish (as long as you change `bilder_set` to the new related name), but it is not necessary to loop through the related `bilder`. If the `{% for bilder in doku.bilder_set.all %}` tag does not output any names, it suggests that there are no `bilder` linked to `Doku` in your database, or they do not have names set. Or perhaps that template snippet you have shown isn't being run by your view.

Comment: thanks man, you are a hero. I feel like the most stupid person. I deleted all bilder related database entries so there wasn't anything to output. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Glad you found the problem. One more thing - I would change `{% for docku in docku %}` to avoid repeating the variable name.